An upperbound for the variance of mean estimator in higher dimensions
I am trying to learn from the paper 
[paper]  http://proceedings.mlr.press/v139/karimireddy21a/karimireddy21a.pdf 
[proofs] http://proceedings.mlr.press/v139/karimireddy21a/karimireddy21a-supp.pdf ,
where we estimate the average of vectors in the Euclidean space $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{d}$ 
and compute the upperbound for the variance of this estimation.
Let us denote the average and its expectation as
\begin{align}
(D1) ~~~ \bar{\mathbf{x}} &:= \frac{1}{|{\mathcal{G}}|}\sum_{i\in \mathcal{G}}\mathbf{x}_{i}
\\
~~~\pmb{\mu} &:= \mathbb{E}[\bar{\mathbf{x}}].
\end{align}
The cardinality of samples ${|\mathcal{G}|}$ is fixed for sampling trials,
and samples ${\mathbf{x}_{i} \in \mathbb{R}^{d}}$ are
independently and identically distributed (i.i.d) according to some
(unknown) probability density function.
We are given an assumption 
\begin{align}
(A1) ~~~~~~~~~~
\mathbb{E}[\|\mathbf{x}_{i} - \mathbf{x}_{j}\|_2^{2}] \leq \rho^{2}
&&\forall i,j \in \mathcal{G}
\end{align}
that the distance between any samples is always bounded in expectation
(Definition C in the paper), and the goal is to show (Appendix D. Proof of Theorem IV)
\begin{align}
(R1) ~~~~~
\mathbb{E}[\|\bar{\mathbf{x}} - \pmb{\mu}\|_{2}^{2}] \leq \frac{\rho^{2}}{|\mathcal{G}|}
\end{align}
that the variance of such a mean estimator (D1) is upperbounded by the right-hand side quantity, using Assumption (A1).
The intuition of this inequality (R1) is that the distance boundness due to Assumption (A1) reduces the variance by factor $\frac{1}{|\mathcal{G}|}$, the cardinality of samples per trial. However, I only end up with much loose bound $\frac{\rho^{2}}{1} \geq \frac{\rho^{2}}{|\mathcal{G}|}$, so I write down my attempt below to gather advice.
\begin{align}
 ~&\mathbb{E}[\| \bar{\mathbf{x}} - \pmb{\mu} \|_{2}^{2}]
&&...(1)\\
=~&\mathbb{E}\left[\left\|
    \frac{1}{|\mathcal{G}|} \sum_{i \in \mathcal{G}}\mathbf{x}_{i}
    - \mathbb{E}[\bar{\mathbf{x}}]
    \right\|_{2}^{2}
\right]
&&...(2)\\
=~&\mathbb{E}\left[\left\|
    \frac{1}{|\mathcal{G}|} \sum_{i \in \mathcal{G}}\mathbf{x}_{i}
    - \mathbb{E}\left[
        \frac{1}{|\mathcal{G}|} \sum_{j \in \mathcal{G}}\mathbf{x}_{j}
    \right]
    \right\|_{2}^{2}
\right]
&&...(3)\\
=~&\mathbb{E}\left[\left\|
    \mathbb{E}\left[
    \frac{1}{|\mathcal{G}|} \sum_{i \in \mathcal{G}}\mathbf{x}_{i}
    - \frac{1}{|\mathcal{G}|} \sum_{j \in \mathcal{G}}\mathbf{x}_{j}
    \right]
    \right\|_{2}^{2}
\right]
&&...(4)~\text{independence of samples}~\mathbf{x}_{i},\mathbf{x}_{j}\\
\leq~&\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}\left[
    \left\|
    \frac{1}{|\mathcal{G}|} \sum_{i \in \mathcal{G}}\mathbf{x}_{i}
    - \frac{1}{|\mathcal{G}|} \sum_{j \in \mathcal{G}}\mathbf{x}_{j}
    \right\|_{2}^{2}
    \right]
\right]
&&...(5)~\text{Jensen's inequality for expectation}\\
=~&\mathbb{E}\left[
    \left\|
    \frac{1}{|\mathcal{G}|} \left(
    \sum_{i \in \mathcal{G}}\mathbf{x}_{i}
    - \sum_{j \in \mathcal{G}}\mathbf{x}_{j}
    \right)\right\|_{2}^{2}
\right]
&&...(6)\\
=~& \frac{1}{|\mathcal{G}|^{2}}
\mathbb{E}\left[
    \left\| 
    \sum_{i \in \mathcal{G}}\mathbf{x}_{i}
    - \sum_{j \in \mathcal{G}}\mathbf{x}_{j}
    \right\|_{2}^{2}
\right]
&&...(7)\\
=~& \frac{1}{|\mathcal{G}|^{2}}
\mathbb{E}\left[
    \left\|
    (\mathbf{x}_{i,1} +  ... + \mathbf{x}_{i,|\mathcal{G}|})
    - (\mathbf{x}_{j,1} +  ... + \mathbf{x}_{j,|\mathcal{G}|})
    \right\|_{2}^{2}
\right]
&&...(8)~\text{verbose writing}\\
=~& \frac{1}{|\mathcal{G}|^{2}}
\mathbb{E}\left[
    \left\| 
    \sum_{i,j \in \mathcal{G}}^{|\mathcal{G}|}
    \left(\mathbf{x}_{i}
    - \mathbf{x}_{j}
    \right)
    \right\|_{2}^{2}
\right]
&&...(9)~\text{equivalent expression to}~(7)\\
\leq~& \frac{1}{|\mathcal{G}|^{2}}
\mathbb{E}\left[
    |\mathcal{G}| \sum_{i,j \in \mathcal{G}}^{|\mathcal{G}|}
    \left\|
    \mathbf{x}_{i}
    - \mathbf{x}_{j}
    \right\|_{2}^{2}
\right]
&&...(10)~\text{Jensen's inequality}~\left\| \sum_{k=1}^{m} \mathbf{v}_{k} \right\|_{2}^{2}
\leq m \sum_{k=1}^{m} \left\| \mathbf{v}_{k} \right\|_{2}^{2}\\
=~& \frac{1}{|\mathcal{G}|}
\mathbb{E}\left[
    \sum_{i,j \in \mathcal{G}}^{|\mathcal{G}|}
    \left\|
    \mathbf{x}_{i}
    - \mathbf{x}_{j}
    \right\|_{2}^{2}
\right]
&&...(11)\\
=~& \frac{1}{|\mathcal{G}|}
\sum_{i,j \in \mathcal{G}}^{|\mathcal{G}|}
\mathbb{E}\left[
    \left\|\mathbf{x}_{i}
    - \mathbf{x}_{j}
    \right\|_{2}^{2}
\right]
&&...(12)~\text{linearity of expectation}\\
\leq~& \frac{1}{|\mathcal{G}|}
\sum_{i,j \in \mathcal{G}}^{|\mathcal{G}|} \rho^{2}
&&...(13)~\text{using Assumption (A1)}\\
=~& \frac{|\mathcal{G}|}{|\mathcal{G}|} \rho^{2}
= \rho^{2}
&&...(14)~\text{worse upperbound than (R1)}.
\end{align}
From (7) to (9), $\mathbf{x}_{i}, \mathbf{x}_{j}$ are random variables from the same i.i. distribution, so the indices' order for each sum does not matter to reduce to a single sum.
In the comment of (10), I multiplied $m^2$ in both sides of the Jensen's inequality given $f(\mathbf{x}) := \|\mathbf{x}\|_{2}^{2}$ and convex-combination weights $\frac{1}{m}$.
For (12) linearity of expectation, I am using
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\left[
    \sum_{i=1}^{N} a_{i} X_{i}
\right] = \sum_{i=1}^{N} a_{i} \mathbb{E}\left[ X_{i} \right]
\end{align}
from Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Properties),
where ${X_{i}}$ is the random variable.
How should I fix my attempt? 
Thanks for your time, and I appreciate your advice.
I am barely experienced with handling expectations.

For $i \neq j$, as $X_i, X_j$ are independent and identically distributed, we have:
$$
    \mathbb{E}[\lVert X_i - X_j \rVert_2^2] = \mathbb{E}[\lVert X_i - \mu \rVert_2^2] + \mathbb{E}[\lVert X_j - \mu \rVert_2^2] = 2 \mathbb{E}[\lVert X_i - \mu \rVert_2^2]
$$
Thus, by (A1) condition, we must have
$$
     \mathbb{E}[\lVert X_i - \mu \rVert^2_2] \le \dfrac{\rho^2}{2}
$$
For simplicity, I denote $n = \vert \mathcal{G}\vert$. Now,
$$
    \begin{align*}
       \mathbb{E}[\lVert \bar{X} - \mu \rVert_2^2] &= \mathbb{E}\left[\left\lVert \dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^n (X_i - \mu)\right\rVert_2^2\right]\\
       &= \dfrac{1}{n^2}\mathbb{E}\left[\left\lVert\sum_{i = 1}^n (X_i - \mu)\right\rVert_2^2 \right]\\
       &\color{red}{\boldsymbol{=}} \dfrac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i = 1}^n \mathbb{E}[\lVert X_i - \mu \rVert_2^2] = \dfrac{\mathbb{E}[\lVert X_1 - \mu \rVert_2^2]}{n} \le \dfrac{\rho^2}{2n}
    \end{align*}
$$
So,
$$
    \mathbb{E}[\lVert \bar{X} - \mu \rVert_2^2] \le \dfrac{\rho^2}{2\vert \mathcal{G} \vert} < \dfrac{\rho^2}{\vert \mathcal{G}\vert}
$$

Explain the third equality $\color{red}{\boldsymbol{=}}$, we have:
$$
    \begin{align*}
         \mathbb{E}\left[\left\lVert\sum_{i = 1}^n (X_i - \mu)\right\rVert_2^2 \right] &= \mathbb{E}\left[\left(\sum_{i = 1}^n (X_i - \mu)\right)^T \left(\sum_{j = 1}^n (X_j - \mu)\right)\right] \\
         &= \sum_{i = 1}^n \sum_{j = 1}^n \mathbb{E}[(X_i - \mu)^T(X_j - \mu)]
    \end{align*}
$$
If $i \neq j$, by independence, we have
$$
     \mathbb{E}[(X_i - \mu)^T(X_j - \mu)] = [\mathbb{E}(X_i - \mu)]^T \mathbb{E}(X_j - \mu) = 0
$$
Otherwise,
$$
    \mathbb{E}[(X_i - \mu)^T(X_i - \mu)] = \mathbb{E}\lVert X_i - \mu \rVert_2^2
$$
Therefore,
$$
     \mathbb{E}\left[\left\lVert\sum_{i = 1}^n (X_i - \mu)\right\rVert_2^2 \right] = \sum_{i = 1}^n \mathbb{E}\lVert X_i - \mu \rVert_2^2
$$

How does this equality ${\dfrac{1}{n^2}\mathbb{E}\left[\left\lVert\sum_{i = 1}^n (X_i - \mu)\right\rVert_2^2 \right] = \dfrac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i = 1}^n \mathbb{E}[\lVert X_i - \mu \rVert_2^2]}$ hold?

@fordicus I have updated my answer explaining this.
